# Get selected QAction text label from QActionGroup

Tags: python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt5

So I am trying to create a PyQt settings tab with a list of options, where I can only choose one option of a list of options. The label of the selected option (e.g. 'A') should then be copied to the self.ID variable, so it can be used as a variable for later functions. Here is what I have written in my **init** function:

```
    self.ID = 0
    self.prevMenu = QtWidgets.QMenu('ID tag', self)
    ag = QtWidgets.QActionGroup(self.prevMenu, exclusive=True)
    self.myID = ['A','B','C','D','E']

    for i in self.myID:
        Action = ag.addAction(QtWidgets.QAction(i, self.prevMenu, checkable=True))
        self.prevMenu.addAction(Action)
        Action.setText(i)
        Action.triggered.connect(lambda item=Action.text(): self.set_ID(Action.text()))
    self.menubar.addMenu(self.prevMenu)

    def set_ID(self, ID):
       print "Which: ", ID
       self.ID = ID
       print self.ID
```

Now my problem is that when I run this, no matter which label I choose, it is only the last element of the list ('E'), that is being transferred to self.ID. I know it must be something about how my variables inherits from each other, but I cannot figure out how. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two mistakes in your code.

1. The `triggered` signal has the `checked` arguments, this means that the "item" argument you use will be "overwritten" by the triggered checked status.
2. The scope of lambda functions is not internal to the function itself, you need to have an actual reference to the value (possibly, a class attribute) or pass it as a lambda optional argument. This is *very* important when using for/while cycles.

You should change the last line of your `for` cycle to this:

```
Action.triggered.connect(lambda checked, item=Action: self.set_ID(item.text())
```

As a personal note, if you are going to use the `set_ID` method only for this purpose, you might prefer to use the action as argument (and read its text from the method) or, eventually, ignore the arguments at all and use the `QObject.sender()` function to retrieve the action that triggered the signal.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I didn't see the error in the lambda function until now. 
I will have a look at the QObject.sender() method and change it.

Comment: You're welcome! That's a common mistake, I struggled with it a couple of times too, now I've learned my lesson :-)